# Armature not deforming mesh in pose mode

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

the problem is simple: I have a human meta rig (that I have no intention of using the generate function on). I'm using that rig as the base for a custom rig for a character with wings. Now I've already added the wing bones. The model itself is complete with no active modifiers apart from the armature modifier. I have also used remove doubles to get rid of any duplicate verts. Now I parent the mesh to the rig with automatic weights.

Now comes the problem: When I enter pose mode, the mesh does not deform and the bones don't even move. The only bone which has any effect is the hip bone, but only when I grab it. I've also checked the bone weighting by going into pose mode, selecting a bone and then <kbd>shift</kbd> clicking the mesh, then pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> and the weights look good.

Here is the blend file https://db.tt/v64hnHnC
I appreciate any help and advice. 
Edit: problem solved. I simply copied and pasted the moddel and rig in a new blend file
Edit: problem solved by copying and pasting model and rig to a new blend file

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your models whenever possible. The URL you provided for instance is blocked by our firewall, so downloads won't be possible on my end. Also consider editing your question and attatching a screenshot of the crucial part: what the weights look like, plus the vertex groups panel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will edit my question. As for the file it seems mine is a bit big.  106 mb but I will try to shrink it.  As for the problem itself I feel like the bones in pose mode are locked somehow